# Ошибка при запуске tomcat - Failed to initialize connector

Tags: linux, tomcat, redhat

Прошу помочь с ошибкой, т.к. не гуглится.
При запуске томката получаю такую ошибку:

```
16-May-2019 10:42:15.966 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-18009"]
16-May-2019 10:42:15.967 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[AJP/1.3-18009]]
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[AJP/1.3-18009]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:549)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:632)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:655)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:309)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:995)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:210)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1086)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:268)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:581)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:993)
        ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 2):

> Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use

Кто-то уже слушает на этом порту.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался